# Start a bunch of programs in Windows in a given order

Tags: windows-7, automation

Each time I start working on my PC, I have a bunch of programs I have to start, some of which depends upon others. I've tried to list them with their dependencies:

- [KeePass](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KeePass)

  - [TrueCrypt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TrueCrypt)

    - foobar2000 (read MP3 from a TrueCrypt encoded volume whose password is stored in KeePass)
  - Chrome (to access my company mail, using a password stored in KeePass)
- Opera
- Firefox
- A [PowerShell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_PowerShell) script used to start a [GlassFish](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GlassFish) domain
- [Eclipse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eclipse_%28software%29) (run as administrator user)
- [Flash Builder](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adobe_Flash_Builder) (run as administrator user)

Is there any utility program that would allow me to sequence that launches in an "easy" way, that would let my computer do all that while I'm waking up?

Notice my computer runs Windows 7, and my user account is automatically logged in.

It seems I forgot to mention I **don"'t want** to write scripts in any form. What I want is a simple GUI, allowing me to select elements from my start menu, and add them to a kind of "delayed start items".

Comment: Regarding your **EDIT**... Do what I do: remove things from startup/registry/msconfig and just have the shortcuts on your Desktop. Then just run what you want, in the order you want by double clicking. If you want to automate this without writing a script you'll find it very difficult for free (as every user and programs dependencies will be different).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a [batch file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batch_file), you can do it. Assume your batch file is **"autoRun.bat"**, place this file in **startup** folder.

Open the batch file in a text editor (say, [Notepad](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Notepad_%28software%29)), write **CMD** commands in your respective order

### Example:

```
ECHO OFF
cls
start notepad.exe
pause
```

In other way round, just copy the shortcut of the **Program/App** and drop it into the **`Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup`** Folder. You will get the program icon at the system tray, indicating that the program is indeed running. To remove, go back to that folder and delete. Note that only the shortcut is involved.

Here, place all the shortcut icons in the order, what you are looking for then it will run in the same order.

Some similar example: [Create a batch file in Windows to start multiple applications](http://www.relativetheory.net/tuts/batch_file.htm)

Answer (score 2):

In the .bat or .cmd file, you can type the following:

```
    @echo <OFF or ON>

    timeout /t <time in seconds>
    start "" "<path to first file or application>"

    timeout /t <time in seconds>
    start "" "<path to second file or application>"
```

Note, that the total timeout for the second (and subsequent applications) is the sum of the former ones - if you for instance have four items you want opened, and the timeout for the first one is set to 10 seconds, the timeout for the second one is set as 20 seconds, and the timeout for the third is set to be 30 seconds - the fourth application or file will take a minute + whatever you set as the timeout.

Comment: +1 Great answer, you could provide more information about creating the batch file or how to figure out the paths.